# Trying to read someone's code re cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to read some code here (not my own) and make changes. So far what I can get from reading it is that if a variable named $cuid is NOT set, it sends a user to a splash page. If it IS set, it sets the cookie to the $cuid variable (which is actually not happening, the cookie isn't updated when you come with a new CUID in GET)

Here's the code:

```
if (!$cuid || $reset)
{
    $cuid="";

    if( $cuid_demo!="samplecu" && $cuid!="75541953" )
        setcookie("cuid","",time() - 31536000); //DELETES COOKIE

    $query="UPDATE cusucceed SET kkc_visits=kkc_visits+1 WHERE id = '$cuid'";
    $result=dbquery($link, $query) or die("error: ".dberror() );
    include("splash.php");
}
else
{
    setcookie("cuid","",time() - 31536000); //DELETES COOKIE
setcookie("cuid",$cuid,time()+604800); //1 week.
    select_db($link) or die("error: ".dberror() );

    if($admin_id)
    {
        $cuid=$cuid;
        $id=$cuid;
    }

    $query="UPDATE cusucceed SET kkc_visits=kkc_visits+1 WHERE id = '$cuid'";
    $result=dbquery($link, $query)or die("Database Server Error 2");
    include("index_main.php");
```

Am I reading that correctly? The else part of the if statement should be setting the cuid cookie to $cuid, if $cuid is set, yes?

Answer (score 0):

**If `$cuid` is unassigned (more explicity, has a `false` result [albeit 0, false, empty]) or it should be `$reset`**,
- Force-empty the cookie (assuming it's not [what appears to be] a test account)
- Display the splash page.

**If `$cuid` is set (and it's not a `$reset`)**,
- Re-declare the cuid cookie, and make it last for a week. Then also display the main page.

In **both instances**,
- Increment the number of times the found `$cuid` has visited the page.

*Although to be honest, it looks like the author wasn't really sure what they were doing based on duplicated code and that they feel the need to empty a cookie before re-declaring it.*

Comment: So to figure out why, when a fresh CUID is in GET, the website isn't updating the cookie, I'll have to find out how the program assigns $CUID.

Comment: I just did a check to see if there was a CUID in the URL, and to set the cookie based on that. Seemed to fix the problem.